# Aggregate and calculate with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I heard that mongoDB was very good at aggregating data compared to, for example SQL server.
I tried to translate an SQL query to a mongoDB query but it's a complete failure :
For SQL server we had like 4 minutes which is manageable and now we top at 34 minutes for 128 days using this request in mongoDB :

```
function(thresholdObs, days) 
{       
    var name = "period-" + days + "j"
    var startDate = new Date('2020', '00', '01');
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *[days]);


    db.getCollection('measures').aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { 
                $and: [
                    {
                        measureDate: {
                            $gte: startDate
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        measureDate: {
                            $lte: endDate
                        }
                    }
                ]
     
            } 
        }, 
        { 
            $addFields: {
                multiplyIahobs: { 
                    $cond: [
                        {$or: [
                            {$eq: ["$averageIAH", null]},
                            {$eq: ["$obs", null]}
                        ]}, 
                        0, 
                        { $multiply: ["$averageIAH", "$obs"] }
                    ]
                },
                multiplyPressionobs: { 
                    $cond: [
                        {$or: [
                            {$eq: ["$averagePressure", null]},
                            {$eq: ["$obs", null]}
                        ]}, 
                        0, 
                        { $multiply: ["$averagePressure", "$obs"] }
                    ]
                },
                multiplyFuitesobs: {
                    $cond: [
                        {$or: [
                            {$eq: ["$averageLeakage", null]},
                            {$eq: ["$obs", null]}
                        ]}, 
                        0, 
                        { $multiply: ["$averageLeakage", "$obs"] }
                    ]
                },
                multiplyinspiratoryPressureobs: { 
                    $cond: [
                        {$or: [
                            {$eq: ["$inspiratoryPressure", null]},
                            {$eq: ["$obs", null]}
                        ]}, 
                        0, 
                        { $multiply: ["$inspiratoryPressure", "$obs"] }
                    ]    
                },
                multiplyexpiratoryPressureobs: {
                    $cond: [
                        {$or: [
                            {$eq: ["$expiratoryPressure", null]},
                            {$eq: ["$obs", null]}
                        ]}, 
                        0, 
                        { $multiply: ["$expiratoryPressure", "$obs"] }
                    ]    
                },
                enoughDays: {
                    $cond: [ { $gte: ["$obs", thresholdObs ] }, 1, 0]
                },
                missingDays: {
                    $cond: [ { $lt: ["$obs", thresholdObs ] }, 1, 0]
                },
                daysWithoutUsage: {
                    $cond: [ { $eq: ["$obs", 0 ] }, 1, 0]
                },
                daysWithData: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$deviceID",
                obsUsage: { $avg: "$obs" }, 
                enoughDays: { $sum: "$enoughDays" },
                missingDays: { $sum: "$missingDays" },
                daysWithoutUsage: { $sum: "$daysWithoutUsage" },
                daysWithData: { $sum: "$daysWithData" },
                sumobs: { $sum: "$obs" },
                sumMultiplyIahobs: { $sum: "$multiplyIahobs" },
                sumMultiplyPressureObs: { $sum: "$multiplyPressionobs" },
                sumMultiplyLeakageObs: { $sum: "$multiplyFuitesobs" },
                sumMultiplyinspiratoryPressureobs: { $sum: "$multiplyinspiratoryPressureobs" },
                sumMultiplyexpiratoryPressureobs: { $sum: "$multiplyexpiratoryPressureobs" },
            } 
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                fullObs: { $divide: [ "$sumobs", days ] }, 
                daysWithoutData: { $subtract: [ days, "$daysWithData" ]},
                averageIAH: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sumobs", 0 ] }, 0, { $divide: ["$sumMultiplyIahobs", "$sumobs"] } ] },
                averagePressure: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sumobs", 0 ] }, 0, { $divide: ["$sumMultiplyPressureObs", "$sumobs"] } ] },
                averageLeakage: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sumobs", 0 ] }, 0, { $divide: ["$sumMultiplyLeakageObs", "$sumobs"] } ] },
                inspiratoryPressure: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sumobs", 0 ] }, 0, { $divide: ["$sumMultiplyinspiratoryPressureobs", "$sumobs"] } ] },
                expiratoryPressure: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sumobs", 0 ] }, 0, { $divide: ["$sumMultiplyexpiratoryPressureobs", "$sumobs"] } ] },
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                [name] : {
                    obsUsage: "$obsUsage", 
                    enoughDays: "$enoughDays",
                    missingDays: "$missingDays",
                    daysWithoutUsage: "$daysWithoutUsage",
                    daysWithData:  "$daysWithData",
                    sumobs: "$sumobs",
                    fullObs: "$fullObs", 
                    daysWithoutData: "$daysWithoutData",
                    averageIAH: "$averageIAH",
                    averagePressure: "$averagePressure",
                    averageLeakage: "$averageLeakage",
                    inspiratoryPressure: "$inspiratoryPressure",
                    expiratoryPressure: "$expiratoryPressure"
                }
            }       
        },
        { 
            $merge: {
             into: "periods",
             on: "_id",         
             whenMatched: "merge",
             whenNotMatched: "insert"
            }
        }
    ],{allowDiskUse: true})
}
```

Before throwing out the baby (mongoDB) with the bathwater (the query). I came here asking if my understanding on how to write a good query is off. Should I try to alter this query to make it work under 4 minutes ? Is it possible ? How ?
**NB : measures collection contains 374.670.449 documents.**

Sample documents :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6127a15fef44a9ed52a5bf62'),
    deviceId: 5,
    measureDateAdded: ISODate('2013-03-15T10:30:35.753Z'),
    measureDate: ISODate('2012-03-20T06:00:00.000Z'),
    obs: 20,
    averageIAH: NumberDecimal('5.50'),
    averagePressure: NumberDecimal('6.30'),
    averageLeakage: NumberDecimal('13.00'),
    inspiratoryPressure: null,
    expiratoryPressure: null
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('6127a15fef44a9ed52a5bfc6'),
    deviceId: 5,
    measureDateAdded: ISODate('2013-03-15T10:30:40.063Z'),
    measureDate: ISODate('2012-06-28T05:00:00.000Z'),
    obs: 197,
    averageIAH: NumberDecimal('5.30'),
    averagePressure: NumberDecimal('6.90'),
    averageLeakage: NumberDecimal('15.00'),
    inspiratoryPressure: null,
    expiratoryPressure: null
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('6127aa2bef44a9ed52a0922a'),
    deviceId: 367959,
    measureDateAdded: ISODate('2019-01-19T14:13:19.620Z'),
    measureDate: ISODate('2019-01-16T11:00:00.000Z'),
    obs: 375,
    averageIAH: NumberDecimal('2.00'),
    averagePressure: NumberDecimal('9.60'),
    averageLeakage: NumberDecimal('6.00'),
    inspiratoryPressure: null,
    expiratoryPressure: null
}
```

What cost the most seems to be the group with deviceId 4+minutes

Comment: 1. mind giving a small data sample so it's easier for me to replicates.

2. what is the scale of this collection. ( and this query )

3. do you have an index built on `mesureDate`?

Comment: 1. sure I'll edit the post 2. what do you mean by scale ? I have an index but it appears to offer no benefit with or without same timing.

Comment: 2. i mean how many documents does the collection have and how many documents are matched in the query.

Comment: 374.670.449 documents and all the documents should be at some point matched.

Comment: the query aggregates the entire collection?

Comment: I made a mistake :  for 180 days (the max threshold)  there is an average of 86.000.000 documents